# trigger jQuery ui dialog from codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

i wonder how i could trigger jquery ui dialog from codebehind? reason i need to do this is i need to save a file before i make the jquery call. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [here](http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/06/03/run-jQuery-code-from-ASPNET-Server-Side.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can dump a script to the page, using somthing like RegisterClientScriptBlock. But either way its going to involve a postback.

Hope that helps