# How do I call up a jQuery UI dialog from ASP.NET code behind without a client-side event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to open a jQuery UI dialog from my C# ASP.NET code based on a value being outside a certain range, rather than based on a button click or other client-side event. Here's the Javascript function that should create the dialog (at the top of the .aspx page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Total out of range dialog
  function ShowRangeDialog() {
    $('#rangeDialog').dialog({
      modal: true,
      width: 'auto',
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,
      close: function (event, ui) {
        $('body').find('#rangeDialog').remove();
      },
      buttons:
      {
        'OK': function () {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here's the dialog div itself (at the bottom of the .aspx page):

```
<div id="rangeDialog" style="display: none;" title="Total out of range">
  <p>
    Your line items total is out of the range allowed by the approval level you chose.
    Please check the approval range and adjust the line items or quantities.
  </p>
</div>
```

And here's the section of the C# code behind that attempts to display the dialog:

```
if (currTotal < lowerLim || currTotal > upperLim)
{
  //Show jQuery dialog telling user that their line items total is out of range
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "dlgOutOfRange",
    "ShowRangeDialog();", true);
}
```

The code in the `if` block is being reached and executed if I step through it in the debugger, but the dialog isn't being displayed. What am I missing?

Comment: I found a typo in my dialog script - it was missing the '#' in front of the "rangeDialog" selector, so there's no way it could have worked because it couldn't have found my dialog div. However, that didn't change anything, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my function slightly, based on a question/answer I found at [How do I open a jQuery UI Dialog from my c# code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704225/how-do-i-open-a-jquery-ui-dialog-from-my-c-sharp-code-behind?rq=1), and now it works. Here's the modified function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Total out of range dialog
  function ShowRangeDialog() {
    $(function() {
      $('#rangeDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        close: function (event, ui) { $('body').find('#rangeDialog').remove(); },
        buttons: { 'OK': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        }
      })
    }).dialog("open");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (currTotal < lowerLim || currTotal > upperLim)
{
  //Show jQuery dialog telling user that their line items total is out of range
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "dlgOutOfRange",
    "ShowRangeDialog();", true);
}
```

You should just be calling the function name.

Also, you may want to try startupscript instead of registerclientscriptblock.  You have to be sure that your script gets added AFTER the function is defined, and not before.

```
if (currTotal < lowerLim || currTotal > upperLim)
{
  //Show jQuery dialog telling user that their line items total is out of range
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "dlgOutOfRange",
    "ShowRangeDialog();", true);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I had, just telling ASP.NET to render the "<script>" tags instead of doing it myself? I tried it anyway, with both RegisterClientScriptBlock and RegisterStartupScript, but it made no difference.

Comment: Did you check to see where the javascript was being rendered in the generated source?  As I mentioned, it has to be rendered after the function definition.

Comment: There are a few reasons why it won't fire.  The big 2 are 1) It's being called too early and 2) There is a syntax error in the function.  

To test #2 I would just call the function on $(document)ready(function(){ShowRangeDialog();});

If it doesn't fire when you call it on document ready, then there's something wrong in the actual function.  Not the function call

Comment: I looked at the generated source, and it definitely gets inserted after my function. And when I put it in `$(document).ready(function(){})` the dialog pops right up. So I don't know what else to try from here.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd.  Try doing a simple alert statement and see if that works.